# 301 Redirect only for posts

Tags: redirect

I have a blog and I'm changing it to a new theme.

Old one has structure blog.com/postname. New one has newblog.com/posts/postname.

I want to redirect ONLY posts from old blog to this new structure, if possible without a plugin.

Pages, archives and everything else that is not a single post will should remain newblog.com/postname structure.

Any ideas?

Comment: From your question, you're mentioning the two domains. `blog.com` & `newblog.com`. Technically, you'll need to 301 every URL, not just for posts but pages & archives too. And, if you only need to move `posts` - well, then there should be a new approach. And, for that you should ask here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify your old theme's `function.php`. Add the following code:

```
function redirect_posts() {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type=='post') {
        return header('location:http://newblog.com/posts/'.$post->post_name);
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'redirect_posts');
```

The `if` codintion will check if the page what's currently viewed is a post and it returns a header redirect to the new blog based on the old blog post's slug.